# How to calculate Mann Kendall Statistics in R

Tags: r

I would like to calculate Mann [Attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdft3.png)Kendall statistics in R. i have an excel sheet with rainfall and years. how would i best get it

Comment: This is basically a typo. The attached image shows that it was the use of quotes around a call to Book1$Mean that prevented this from succeeding.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the attached image you should not put `Book1$Mean` in quotes. Try using:

```
MannKendall(Book1$Mean)
```